# Writing values from a channel to a file

Tags: nextflow

What is the best way to write values from a channel to a file?

Consider the following example:

```
nextflow.enable.dsl=2

workflow {

    ch = Channel.of('a', 'b', 'c')

    file('test.txt').withWriter {out -> 
        out.println "My values are:"
        ch.subscribe {
            out.println "$it"
            println "$it"
        }
    }
}
```

This will correctly output `a`, `b`, `c` to stdout, but `test.txt` will only contain `My values are:` and nothing else. Clearly, `.subscribe{}` is iterating over the values (otherwise it wouldn't display them to stdout) and writing to the file is working (otherwise the file would not have `My values are:`), but why would it not write the values to the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way is to use the [`collectFile`](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#collectfile) operator: https://nextflow-io.github.io/patterns/collect-into-file/

If you don't need sorted output and would like the entries appended as they're emitted, you could also use `sort: false` to disable content sorting and the [`concat`](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#concat) operator to prepend the header:

```
workflow {

    my_header = Channel.value( "My values are:" )
    my_values = Channel.of( 'foo', 'bar', 'baz' )
    
    my_header
        .concat( my_values )
        .collectFile( name: 'test.txt', newLine: true, sort: false )
        .view()

}
```

Results:

```
$ nextflow run main.nf 
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 23.04.1
Launching `main.nf` [marvelous_marconi] DSL2 - revision: c9242fbc73
/path/to/work/tmp/ea/d8ec4488443faf816cb6a213f3bad7/test.txt
```

Contents of
`/path/to/work/tmp/ea/d8ec4488443faf816cb6a213f3bad7/test.txt`:

```
My values are:
foo
bar
baz
```

---

Note that you could also use a closure to write to the file, for example:

```
workflow {

    def test_file = new File( 'test.txt' )
    def write_value = { value ->
        test_file << value + "\n"
    }

    my_values = Channel.of( 'foo', 'bar', 'baz' )

    Channel
        .value( "My values are:" )
        .concat( my_values )
        .subscribe { write_value(it) }
}
```

```
$ cat test.txt 
My values are:
foo
bar
baz
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the following is a workaround that achieves the desired behavior:

```
nextflow.enable.dsl=2

workflow {
    Channel.of('a', 'b', 'c')
        .map{ it ->
            "My values are:\n$it\n"
        }
        .collectFile(
            name: 'test.txt',
            storeDir:'.',
            keepHeader: true,
            skip: 1
        )
}
```

The workaround involves prepending the header to every element, allowing it to be captured by `.collectFile()`.
The output file will contain:

```
My values are:
a
c
b
```